# jvectormap - Selectable continents in world map

Tags: jvectormap

Im am using the jvectormap world map and I really want an combination of the world map and the continents map. With the accent on the continents selector.

http://jvectormap.com/maps/world/world/
http://jvectormap.com/maps/world/continents/

The goal is to see all the coutries (url1) and highlighting the whole continent on hover. (url2)

I don't know if this is possible at all, any help wil be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
            $('#map').vectorMap({
                map: 'es_mill',
                regionsSelectable: true
            });
        });
```